# LWJGL/OpenGL: Handling dynamic voxel terrain with dyanmic LOD with VBOs and VAOs

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, buffer, lwjgl

EDIT:

I have chunks with constantly changing levels of detail.  Whenever a chunk's level of detail changes, I must recompute the vertices to be drawn.  The amount of vertices changing dynamically because of this.

My problem is, I don't know how to go about being able to draw this.  I thought I could just delete the old buffers and then reload the new ones.  Is this efficient or just a bad idea to delete and reload buffers every few seconds?  Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Here is how I thought about doing it:

```
//delete old buffers
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vboID);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vboiID);

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoID);

//reload buffers with new vertex data
    vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer, GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    vboiID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboiID);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer, GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

There has to be a better way to do this than that though...  I am probably just missing some key concept as usual so please let me know if I am just being a complete moron for trying to do it this way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try work with glBufferSubData(), it's must be what you need.

Comment: Does that allow me to dynamically add data into the list instead of just overwriting already existent data?

Comment: I'm really don't know, but i read about it. I think that this is wrong place for question about OpenGL.